# Symfony: how to load vendor's image using Assetic?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm starting at creating my own bundles and upload them to github.

I have just created this: https://github.com/Ziiweb/FrontendBundle

Inside the bundle, there is an image here: https://github.com/Ziiweb/FrontendBundle/tree/master/Resources/public/images

And I'm loading that image this way below inside a template in the same bundle, in the same way as it said in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-images):

```
{% image '@ZiiwebFrontendBundle/Resources/public/images/ajax-loader.gif' %}
<img class="loader" src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

*The problem:* after installing the bundle (composer) in another project, I get the error below when trying to request the template where the image is:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_0b1c853_0" as
>   such route does not exist.") in
>   ZiiwebFrontendBundle:Default:contact.html.twig at line 15.

I get the same message using this code:

```
  {% image 'bundles/ziiwebfrontend/images/ajax-loader.gif' %}
  <img class="loader" src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
  {% endimage %}
```

Yes, I have installed the assets using `assets:install` so my image is at `web/bundles/ziiwebfrontend/images/ajax-loader.gif`.

NOTE: I think I have Assetic installed correctly.. I have used these [3 steps](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#installing-and-enabling-assetic).

Comment: Maybe an assetic:dump ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed to add same bundle in config.yml

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [YourBundleName]
```

Comment: thanks, it seems it is working. Anyway after adding that line you mention, then I have removed it and it keeps on working.. event if I clear the cache. O_o